# Change color on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement, toggle

```
$("span").hide();

$("div").click(function(){
$(this).css({ 'backgroundColor': 'red' },200);
},function(){
$(this).css({ 'backgroundColor': 'pink' },200);
});

$("div").click(function(){
$("span").toggle();
});
```

I have a button and a menu. When you click on the pink button, the menu is opened.
What I want : when the menu is opened, the button become red, and when is closed, the button get back to pink.

**MY JS : http://jsfiddle.net/fhtdngdj/2/**

Comment: bro you can use toggle too

Answer (score 1):

Create two CSS classes, pink and red. Then use:

```
$("span").hide();
$("div").click(function () {
    $("span").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fhtdngdj/3/)**

Comment: Almost perfect ! But if I also want an "hover" effect ? http://jsfiddle.net/fhtdngdj/11/

Answer (score 0):

Could also do a check if the menu is visible and add the corresponding class or edit the background-color attribute.

```
$("div").click(function(){
$("span").toggle();
if($("#menu").is(':visible')){
    //or toggle class with toggleClass()
    $('#button').css('background-color','red');
}
else
    //or toggle class with toggleClass()
    $('#button').css('background-color','pink');
});
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fhtdngdj/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use toggleClass on both click and hover: http://jsfiddle.net/fhtdngdj/17/

```
$("span").hide();

$("div").click(function () {
    $("span").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});

$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

Then just add the appropriate background-color to each css class as is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Note, the slight differences between mine and j08691 's answers are due to the question being very slightly ambiguous. I presumed that you want the hover colour to be a third color, but I may be wrong, take your pick.